# Rotate causing crash due to onQueryTextListener?

Tags: android, rotation

I have a search bar for a list of players. When they user types in the search bar it filters the list. Noticed that when the device rotates it crashes. The logic for the search view is carried out in a separate  adapter. Is there a way to amend the code so that it does not crash on rotate? The error i get is
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter com.example.android.prototype2.views.PlayerListAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference

```
 //Assign the search view variable
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_users);
        //Set onQueryListener for when text is entered into the search bar
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            //When text is changed filter the results from the playerlist adapter
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The adapter logic is in the playerlistAdapter

```
  private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<UserHelperClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(playerListFull);

            } else {
                //trim -empty spaces removed
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (UserHelperClass player : playerListFull) {
                    if (player.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(player);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            playersList.clear();
            playersList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Where are you populating the adapter?

Comment: This is being done in the player list adaper. see edit

Comment: The adapter is null and when you do `adapter.getFilter()` you get a null object reference. Make sure you are populating the adapter before you do `adapter.getFilter()`. This also tells that you are not populating the adapter in any Activity lifecycle method like `onCreate()` or `onResume()` because of which when you rotate the screen your adapter does not gets populated.

Comment: The best way to see if the adapter is null or not is to put a debug point at `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)` and then rotate the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by adding  if (adapter != null), before adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);